# Why are fourier series real?

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-series

Consider an assertion made on [Wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FourierSeries.html) about the Fourier series:

[image]

**Question:** How can one just assert that $f(x)$ is a real-valued function and not a complex-valued one? That is, how can one just assert that

$$
f(x) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty A_n e^{inx}?
$$

If $A_n \in \mathbb{C}$ and $e^{inx} \in \mathbb{C}$, then wouldn't it be an extraordinary coincidence if $f(x)$ happened to be in $\mathbb{R}$ as well?

Comment: It's not an assertion, it's a hypothesis. We're starting with a real-valued function and seeing what we can do with it.

Comment: There is a formula relating the complex coefficients and the real coefficients.

Comment: Yes, we're asking, if we can write a real-valued function as the above formula, then... There are actual conditions on $A_n$ for the function $f$ to be ensured to be real-valued, namely, we need $A_{-n}=\overline{A_n}$.

Comment: I see, and thanks.  I think it's poorly worded in Wolfram then. Instead of "Write..." it should be "Suppose..." to make it clear it's a hypothesis.

Comment: The phrase "Consider a real-valued function $f(x)$" means "Suppose $f(x)$ is real-valued."  We can then write the fixed real-valued function $f(x)$ as a series $f(x) = \sum A_n e^{inx}$ and see what must be true of the coefficients $A_n$.

Comment: @JesseMadnick "Consider a real-valued function $f(x)$" is perfectly clear; what's not clear is "Write...".

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that all integrals in this snippet are strictly complex-valued?

Comment: Every real number *is* a complex number. What do you mean by strictly "complex-valued"?